# Dimension of $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{3},xy,y^{2})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to find the dimension and a basis of $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{3},xy,y^{2})$. I think the easiest way would just be to understand how $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{3},xy,y^{2})$ looks like. The ideal $I=ax^{3}+xy+cy^{2}$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Am I right in thinking $[ax^{3}+bxy+cy^{2}]=[0]$ and so $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{3},xy,y^{2})=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{3}y$ so ${1,x,x^{2},y}$ is the basis. But I haven't defined the maps between rings $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{3},xy,y^{2})$.

Comment: "I haven't defined the maps between rings $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{3},xy,y^{2})$" Yes, you have, implicitly. $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C[x, y]$ is by including $\Bbb C$ as the constant polynomials, and $\Bbb C[x, y]\to \Bbb C[x, y]/(x^3, xy, y^3)$ is the canonical quotient map. You are using the composition of these two maps. I don't even know whether you _can_ have any other map, but at any rate this is the most common and, objectively, by far the most natural map. If anyone ever does something else, they will tell you. Preferably in bold font.

Comment: Please do not edit the post in such a way that renders the current answers incomprehensible.

Comment: Draw a picture of $Z\times Z$, where each coordinate $(i,j)$ represents the monomial $x^iy^j$. In this plane modding out by a monomial ideal like yours amounts to "killing" everything appearing above and to the right of each generator. Whatever element is left is an element of the basis.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal $(x^3,xy,y^2)$ is a *monomial ideal*, an ideal generated by monomials.
It's easy to get a $\Bbb C$-basis for $\Bbb C[x,y]/I$,
where $I$ is a monomial ideal, since one can take
the monomials in $x$ and $y$ which are not divisible by the monomials in the
generating set for $I$.
Here this basis consists of $1$, $x$, $x^2$ and $y$, as you say
(or more strictly the of cosets $1+(x^3,xy,y^2)$, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $I=\langle x^3,xy,y^2\rangle$ is a monomial ideal. The only monomials not lying in this ideal are those of $B=\{1,x,x^2,y\}$. These monomials are called the standard monomials of $I$. They form a vector space basis for $A={\Bbb C}[x,y]/I$.

This situation can be generalized to the case when $I$ is a zero-dimensional ideal of ${\Bbb C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. More upon request.